# Delete rows in Excel based on list of row numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv

I have a Excel file of names that I am requesting historical testing data on.  The list is over 20,000 rows.  The system returns a csv file of the row numbers that contain names that do not match.  It will not process the file unless all rows match.  How can I delete the rows in my file based on the csv file I get back other than manually deleting 1000s of rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a match formula should do the trick. something like =MATCH(ROW()-1,$D$2:$D$4,0), where row()-1 should be altered to line up the data in your list to the csv data; $D2:$D$4 should be the csv array, and 0 is looking for the exact match.

The result of the formula would be #N/A for non matches (keepers) or the position in the array for matches (deletes). Just filter out the matches, and you should be good to go on the upload.